# Creating a wallapaper script which changes from time to time (desired time)

Tags: bash, arch-linux, kde, manjaro, wallpaper

So I wanted to copy what's on mac os where the desktop wallpaper changes to the time

I use Manjaro with KDE

The following code will change the wallpaper on KDE with the given path to the picture

```
qdbus org.kde.plasmashell /PlasmaShell org.kde.PlasmaShell.evaluateScript 'var allDesktops = desktops();print (allDesktops);for (i=0;i<allDesktops.length;i++) {d = allDesktops[i];d.wallpaperPlugin = "org.kde.image";d.currentConfigGroup = Array("Wallpaper", "org.kde.image", "General");d.writeConfig("Image", "<<<<PATH>>>>")}'
```

this is copied from another place where it uses more than one picture
this code works just by running it on the terminal

so I wanted to create 5 of them with changed wallpaper to their respective times

naming them noon.sh morning.sh and so on

these files are made and given their wanted permissions

```
chmod u+x <filename>
```

after making those even bashing them works

```
./noon.sh
```

I cant use crontab on this because it wont schedule to a specific time as I know (I may be wrong)

so now I have the files and I typed in terminal ./PATH/noon | at 11:00

which did work and changed the wallpaper in the given time

so now I have another file with 24 of em changing the wallpaper from 1H intervals

like this

```
#!/bin/sh


echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/night.sh\n" | at 00:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/night.sh\n" | at 01:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/night.sh\n" | at 02:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/night.sh\n" | at 03:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/night.sh\n" | at 04:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/night.sh\n" | at 05:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/morning.sh\n" | at 06:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/morning.sh\n" | at 07:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/morning.sh\n" | at 08:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/noon.sh\n" | at 09:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/noon.sh\n" | at 10:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/noon.sh\n" | at 11:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/noon.sh\n" | at 12:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/noon.sh\n" | at 13:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/noon.sh\n" | at 14:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/noon.sh\n" | at 15:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/evening.sh\n" | at 16:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/evening.sh\n" | at 17:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/dusk.sh\n" | at 18:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/night.sh\n" | at 19:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/night.sh\n" | at 20:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/night.sh\n" | at 21:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/night.sh\n" | at 22:00
echo "./Documents/WallpaperScript/night.sh" | at 23:00
```

and with the help of the settings page

I used this as a startup script

it doesn't seem to work

but if I run the `atq` command I can see the output where the at processes are scheduled

but it doesn't work

can someone please help :3

PS sorry for my bad English and I'm still new to Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set cron to run at specific times, maybe it's not exact to the second or the decimals, but would you really notice?

This is my suggested `/etc/crontab`:

```
00 * * * * *user* /home/*user*/Documents/WallpaperScript/setWallpaper.sh
```

And inside the script you can have a variable like `HH=$(date +%H)` to know what time it is and which image to use.

It still wouldn't work from cron because cron runs in the background and doesn't know about your display.

I don't know about at, but I think it's the same.

Try add `DISPLAY=:0` before you call `qdbus`.

So here's what you should run:

```bsh
DISPLAY=:0 qdbus org.kde.plasmashell /PlasmaShell org.kde.PlasmaShell.evaluateScript 'var allDesktops = desktops(); print (allDesktops); for (i=0;i<allDesktops.length;i++) {d = allDesktops[i]; d.wallpaperPlugin = "org.kde.image"; d.currentConfigGroup = Array("Wallpaper", "org.kde.image", "General"); d.writeConfig("Image", "<<<<PATH>>>>")}'
```

As a bonus (I have the same script running from cron), you can also set the lockscreen to the same image:

```bsh
DISPLAY=:0 kwriteconfig5 --file /home/*user*/.config/kscreenlockerrc --group Greeter --group Wallpaper --group org.kde.image --group General --key Image "file://<<<<PATH>>>>"
```

Comment: Thanks it helped